# jQuery Mobile: Dynamic content not loading when I return to a page

Tags: dynamic, jquery-mobile, loading, page-refresh

My data from `getmovies.php` is working correctly and loading into `#moviesPage` the FIRST time I load the page. However, if I navigate away from `#moviesPage` and then return to it the content does not reload. The header and footer appear and I can see that the unpopulated `<ul>` is also there, just not any of the dynamically loaded `<li>s`.

My code is below. **Any thoughts on how I can get my dynamic data to load when I return to a page?**

```
$( '#moviesPage' ).live( 'pagebeforecreate',function(event){
  getMoviesList();
});

function getMoviesList() {
  $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getmovies.php', function(data) {
    $('#moviesList li').remove();
    movies = data.items;
    $.each(movies, function(index, movie) {
      $('#moviesList').append('<li>' +
      '<img src="posters' + movie.poster + '"/>' +
      '<div class="movie-toprow"><h4>' + movie.title + '</h4>' +
      '</li>').listview('refresh');
        });
    });
}
```

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.1.0-rc.1, but was having the same issue with 1.0.1. This is for a mobile app that will be used on iOS, Android, and other mobile platforms.

**BONUS:** For now I just want the content to reload. However, eventually I would like to cache the `title` and `movie poster image` for each unique `movieID`, but still pull some dynamic data in for each `<li>` (I removed this other data to simplify my code for this question). I'm not very familiar with caching, but would like to know how to load both new data and cached data when the page is revisited. I know I could use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` for the `title`, but how do I make it easy for the image to be reloaded without making another request to the server?

Thank you for any insight you can share on my primary or bonus question! -Mark

Comment: How are you transitioning from page to page? Can you post this code?

Comment: I'm simply transitioning from page to page with normal links. For example, `<a href="index.html">Movies</a>` and `<a href="profile.html">Profile</a>`. Each `HTML` file has its own `<div id="moviesPage" data-role="page">` container.

Comment: So when navigating back and for are you using the page id like this #moviesPage to #index to #profile or using it like this moviesPage.html to index.html to profile.html?

Comment: to move back to a cached page use the #moviesPage method, so instead of index.html use the page Id #index or #profile

Comment: I have just been using links like `index.html` and `profile.html`, not the `IDs`.

Comment: @Phill Pafford Thanks! Using `#moviesPage` does work for loading the content (I did have it set for `data-dom-cache="true"`). However, I have a `navbar` in my `data-role="footer"` and it seems it would need to link to `profile.html` first and then to `#profilePage` after it had first been visited. Additionally, the `ui-btn-active` class is not present on the `#moviesPage` nav button when I return to the page. Is there any easy solution to this need for dual linking or do I just need to create some javascript to change the links once a page has first been visited.

Comment: If you have another question please post it in a separate question. Also if the advice solved this question please select it as the answer as I posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to move back to a cached page use the #moviesPage method, so instead of index.html use the page Id #index or #profile

-- From comments