# jQuery Mobile: Is there a better way of linking to and loading cached pages?

Tags: jquery, caching, jquery-mobile, hyperlink, session-storage

I have a jQuery Mobile app. For this example, I'm using two pages: **Movies** (index.html - #moviesPage) and **Profile** (profile.html - #profilePage). These are both linked to in my my navbar in the `data-role="footer" div`.

It seems the navbar would need to link to `profile.html` first (to load and cache the content and data) and then to `#profilePage` after it had first been visited. Additionally, the `ui-btn-active` class is not present on the `#moviesPage` nav button when I return to the page. Is there any easy solution to this need for dual linking or do I just need to create some javascript to change the links once a page has first been visited. Do I even need dual linking or is there some way in jQuery Mobile to just have the link as `profile.html` and it will know if it has already been visited to load the cached content?

One possible solution I've started on is where once a page is visited `sessionStorage.profilePage = 'visited'` and if `visited` its link in the navbar changes from `profile.html` to `#profilePage`. I also have put together the following to take care of the `ui-btn-active` issue.

```
var activePage = $('div[data-role*="page"]').attr("id");

if (activePage == "moviesPage") {
  //Add class="ui-btn-active" to #moviesLink
}
```

This is a follow-up question to my original question here: [jQuery Mobile: Dynamic content not loading when I return to a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620314/jquery-mobile-dynamic-content-not-loading-when-i-return-to-a-page)

Thank you for any additional thoughts or insights into this. -Mark